# Find the $\theta$ of $\frac{a}{\cos\theta}+\frac{b}{\sin\theta}=c$

Tags: trigonometry

I am wondering how to find the $\theta$ of $\frac{a}{\cos\theta}+\frac{b}{\sin\theta}=c$, given $a, b, c\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, and $a+b\leq c$. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest first combining the fractions by given them a common denominator and then multiplying by that common denominator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your equation in the form
$$a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)=c\sin(x)\cos(x)$$ and Substitute $$\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$ and $$\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$

Comment: hmm, this is degree $4$ equation, not much simpler than solving the original one.